# If statment of a cell calculated using formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

My formula is giving me unexpected responses.

```
=IF(I5+H5=0,"Paid","Due")
```

see below

```
    H      I       J      k
-£34.40 £34.40  £0.00   Due
```

Cell H is calculated with this

```
=(SUM(F5+G5))*-1
```

See correct output with exact same formula on same worksheet

```
=IF(I3+H3=0,"Paid","Due")

  H          I        J      K
-£205.44  £205.44   £0.00   Paid
```

Cell H is calculated he same

```
=(SUM(F3+G3))*-1
```

Any ideas why the top calculation not correct but the bottom one is.

Comment: Because the sum `=(SUM(F5+G5))*-1` actually might not be `-£34.40` but something like `-£34.400001234`? 

Increase the decimal places and check

Comment: You are right, thank you. =(SUM(F5+G5))*-1 = -£34.404. Is there an easy way too force 2 decimal places?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: You can use ROUND to get 2 decimals like this, `=ROUND(-F5-G5,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the floating point issue.  You should not compare floating point numbers directly with =   because computers can't store the full decimal places.   Just like if you divide 1 dollar by 3, you end up with .3333333333333 cents,  well if you add 3 of those you don't necessarily get back 1 dollar, but slightly less due to the "lost" 3333's at the end.  The proper way to compare is using a Delta threshold, meaning "how close" it needs to be.

so instead of

```
if (a+b=c,"paid", "due")
```

you would do

```
if(ABS(c-(a+b))<.01, "paid", "due")
```

so in that case .01 is the delta, or "how close" it has to be. It has to be within 1 cent.  the formula literally means "if the absolute value of the difference between c and (a+b) is less than 1 cent, return paid, else return due.  (of course, this will say due if they overpaid, so keep that in mind)

you should always do this.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I changed the value to something ridiculous and still not working. =IF(I5+H5>100000,"Paid","Due")

Comment: so =IF(I5+H5>100000,"Paid","Due") is saying "Paid"???  if so, instead of Paid do =IF(I5+H5>100000,(I5+H5),"Due") to see what value it's getting

Comment: I got it sorted, thanks for you help. I created a new work book and copied the formulas over and pasted the info back in, seems to have done the trick.  When pasting the formulas I could see where the extra decimal places were coming from and corrected them manually and I know what caused them now so I hopefully won't come across the problem again. You put me in the right direction for future .